# Filter out " TIC Read Status" in Xcode console?

Tags: xcode

Is it a way to filter out " TIC Read Status" lines in Xcode console? It is a hassle to see this content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good option. You may want to keep it disabled as console doesn't provide useful information when debugging crashes like `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

Still, for people who are wondering how to silence the warning and until a better fix is available you may keep following variable handy and toggle as needed.

Use `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` environment variable under Arguments in the product schemes to avoid console getting flooded with such warnings.

Note B: Enable it to see the effect.

Source: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/disable-os-logging-in-xcode-8-ec6d38502532

[image]

Comment: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disables all logging, which is pretty bad advice.